# Cross compilation of c++ code on Linux 14.04 64 bit to windows7 64 bit failed

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, mingw, cross-compiling

I was trying to cross-compile from linux64 bit to windows7 64 bit some source code with the following command line

> x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ eval-table.cc -o hello7.exe -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic -I /usr/include -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I /usr/local/include -std=gnu++11

The error looks like this

One of the typical errors being

```
error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __time_t time_t’
typedef __time_t time_t;

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstdint:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:376,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/include/stdint.h:122:27: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long unsigned int uintptr_t’
 typedef unsigned long int uintptr_t;
                           ^
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:10:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstddef:42,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:40,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/config.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/_mingw.h:412:44: error: ‘uintptr_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef long long unsigned int uintptr_t’
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 uintptr_t;
                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/sched.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/pthread.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/include/time.h:75:18: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __time_t time_t’
 typedef __time_t time_t;
                  ^
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:10:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstddef:42,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:40,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/config.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/_mingw.h:481:20: error: ‘time_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef __time64_t time_t’
 typedef __time64_t time_t;
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstdlib:72,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2815,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:109:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __ssize_t ssize_t’
 typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;
                   ^
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:10:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstddef:42,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:40,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/config.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/_mingw.h:387:35: error: ‘ssize_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef long long int ssize_t’
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 ssize_t;
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cwctype:50:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from /usr/include/boost/assert.hpp:82,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/function_base.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/function1.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/include/wctype.h:52:27: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long unsigned int wctype_t’
 typedef unsigned long int wctype_t;
                           ^
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:10:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstddef:42,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:40,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/config.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/_mingw.h:444:24: error: ‘wctype_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef short unsigned int wctype_t’
 typedef unsigned short wctype_t;
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/sign.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:167,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from eval-table.cc:23:
/usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:236:65: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
     static const uint64_t sign     = ((uint64_t)0x80000000u) << 32;
                                                                 ^
/usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:237:64: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
     static const uint64_t exponent = ((uint64_t)0x7ff00000) << 32;
                                                                ^
/usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:240:38: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
         = (((uint64_t)0x000fffff) << 32) + ((uint64_t)0xffffffffu);
                                      ^
/usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:296:63: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
     static const uint64_t sign     = (uint64_t)0x80000000u << 32;
                                                               ^
/usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:297:62: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
     static const uint64_t exponent = (uint64_t)0x7ff00000 << 32;
                                                              ^
/usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:300:36: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
         = ((uint64_t)0x000fffff << 32) + (uint64_t)0xffffffffu;
                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/chrono:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/mutex:39,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencog/util/Logger.h:31,
                 from eval-table.h:31,
                 from eval-table.cc:31:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ratio:214:7: error: static assertion failed: This library calls __builtin_clzll on uintmax_t, which is unsafe on your platform. Please complain to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/
       static_assert(sizeof (uintmax_t) == sizeof (unsigned long long),
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/ratio/ratio.hpp:47:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/chrono/duration.hpp:41,
                 from /usr/include/boost/chrono/system_clocks.hpp:62,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/local/include/moses/comboreduct/combo/enum_type.h:31,
                 from ../table/../interpreter/../combo/vertex.h:43,
                 from ../table/../interpreter/eval.h:35,
                 from ../table/table.h:45,
                 from ../table/table_io.h:40,
                 from eval-table.h:33,
                 from eval-table.cc:31:
/usr/include/boost/ratio/ratio_fwd.hpp:64:81: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 typedef ratio<BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1), BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1000000000000000000)> atto;
                                                                                 ^
/usr/include/boost/ratio/ratio_fwd.hpp:65:81: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 typedef ratio<BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1),    BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1000000000000000)> femto;
                                                                                 ^
/usr/include/boost/ratio/ratio_fwd.hpp:66:81: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 typedef ratio<BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1),       BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1000000000000)> pico;
                                                                                 ^
/usr/include/boost/ratio/ratio_fwd.hpp:77:81: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 typedef ratio<      BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1000000000000), BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1)> tera;
                                                                                 ^
/usr/include/boost/ratio/ratio_fwd.hpp:78:81: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 typedef ratio<   BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1000000000000000), BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1)> peta;
                                                                                 ^
/usr/include/boost/ratio/ratio_fwd.hpp:79:81: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 typedef ratio<BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1000000000000000000), BOOST_RATIO_INTMAX_C(1)> exa;
                                                                                 ^
```

I have searched the internet why this happend and it seems the cross-compiler is searching for the native gcc libraries. But I don't know how to solve that, either by renaming some folder in linux shared libraries or changing a PATH variable temporarily. Can anybody tell me what to do exactly?

I know I could use MXE cross-compiler (am not an expert in Linux to quickly figure out how to use it) but I already took many days trying to figure this out and would like to end the saga quickly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like a bug/feature in the MingW installation (or perhaps "bug/feature" of installing a more modern C library set) - I think you can fix it by removing the offending duplicate definitions...

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you're cross compiling you shouldn't have your local system headers  in the include path...

Comment: sorry. forgot to specify it is c++ program i am trying to compile and create exe file of

Comment: @MatsPetersson, no it is not a MinGW installation bug ... OP isn't even using MinGW -- he is using mingw-w64, which is **not** the same thing. However, in this case, it is exactly as user657267 says: OP has explicitly specified inclusion of headers belonging to his native (Linux) system compiler, which is 100% the wrong thing to do, when cross-compiling.